# Doctorine/Dbal - Update table migration adding unwanted "Auto Increment" on integer (not increments)

Tags: laravel, doctrine, laravel-migrations, doctrine-dbal

I'm using Laravel 6.6.0 and Doctrine/Dbal 2.10.

I need to update a migration, and have followed the info in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#modifying-columns).

**I have a small unsigned non-auto-incrementing integer which I need to change to an integer.**

I actually want it to be `mediumint`, but I understand from the Laravel docs that this isn't supported.

> Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.
> My initial migration is the following:

```
...
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->smallInteger('membership_code')->unsigned();
$table->char('name')->nullable();
...
```

And having installed the dbal package, I am trying the following migration to update the `membership_code` column:

```
$table->integer('membership_code', 5)->unsigned()->change();
```

But when I run the migrate command, I get the following:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: ALTER TABLE member_centres CHANGE membership_code membership_code INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
```

**I don't understand why it's adding `AUTO_INCREMENT` to the migration?**

I don't have it as an `increments` type, so why is it adding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `integer` isn't a size, it is a boolean for whether it should be an autoincrement field or not.

```
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```

Comment: Thank you! You've just saved me hours of tearing my hair out! Couldn't see the wood for the trees!